# Delphi Indy10 TCPServer fails to disconnect under Linux

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have a Server using `TIdTCPServer`.

During initial connection of a client, I assign a local `DTBClient` to it as follows:

```pascal
class procedure TDTBEventHandlers.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ADTBClient: TDTBClient;
begin
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := false;
    if (AContext.Connection.IOHandler is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase) then
      TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := true;

    ADTBClient := TDTBClient(AContext);

    ADTBClient.IP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
    ADTBClient.Callsign := MakeRandomCallsign;
   // etc
...
end
```

When thing go wrong with the Client, I try and disconnect them as follows:

Note1: When the `List` is NOT `nil`, then the lock/unlock is done by the calling procedure.

Note2: I forced this situation by pulling the network cable from the Client, so there is no TCP reset.

```pascal
function DisconnectClient(ADTBClient: TDTBClient; List: TIdContextList; Server: TDTBPort):boolean;
var
  Index: integer;
  UnLock: boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  Unlock := false;
  try
    if List = nil then
    begin
      if Server = dpOne then List := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList else
      if Server = dpTwo then List := IdTCPServer2.Contexts.LockList;
      Superlog('DisconnectClient: List=nil? Server='+integer(Server).ToString,d_warning);
      Unlock := true;
    end;

    try
      Index := List.IndexOf(TDTBClient(ADTBClient));
      if Index >= 0 then
      begin
        result := true;
        SuperLog('DisconnectClient: Disconnecting: Callsign='+ADTBClient.Callsign+'  Server='+integer(Server).ToString+'. Index='+Index.ToString);
       
        TIdContext(List[Index]).Connection.Disconnect;
      
      end;

    finally
      if UnLock then
      begin
        if Server = dpOne then IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList else
        if Server = dpTwo then IdTCPServer2.Contexts.UnlockList;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

The Log shows this:

```
Aug 20 05:17:16 zeus sartrackserver[32044]: DisconnectClient: Disconnecting: Callsign=_DQKIK  Server=1. Index=3
Aug 20 05:17:16 zeus sartrackserver[32044]: IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1StatusInfo: SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"

Aug 20 05:17:21 zeus sartrackserver[32044]: [0] KeepAliveTimerEvent: Port 1: (NOT AllSyncsComplete): Timeout for Client: Callsign=_DQKIK, IP=122.57.206.196 PongCounter=8 Disconnecting on Index: 3
Aug 20 05:17:21 zeus sartrackserver[32044]: Superuser: DisconnectClient: Disconnecting: Callsign=_DQKIK  Server=1. Index=3
Aug 20 05:17:21 zeus sartrackserver[32044]: ERROR: DisconnectClient: Client failed to disconnect on Index: 3
Aug 20 05:17:21 zeus sartrackserver[32044]: DisconnectClient: After List: 0: IZ3VIV
Aug 20 05:17:21 zeus sartrackserver[32044]: DisconnectClient: After List: 1: W7QQ-2
Aug 20 05:17:21 zeus sartrackserver[32044]: DisconnectClient: After List: 2: ZL4FOX-5
Aug 20 05:17:21 zeus sartrackserver[32044]: DisconnectClient: After List: 3: _DQKIK <<<<<
```

It looks like the disconnect has taken place on the TCP level, but the entry has not been removed from the `List`.

The next big problem is that during shutdown, the TCP server hangs on `IdTCPServer1.Active := false;` where it is disconnecting all clients, but when it hits the client which was already disconnected it locks up. And this causes the (Linux) server to hang during shutdown, and a `kill -9` is required, and other data is lost.

I have never seen this happen before under Windows, but I now see it in the new Linux version.

I am using Delphi 10.4 with the included Indy10 version.

UPDATE 1

I have added load of debug log entries through the Indy10 system.
As per Remy's advise, I now call Connection.Socket.Binding.CloseSocket instead of Connection.Disconnect.
However, today the intermittend problem happened again, and this time I could see the CloseSocked never happened, and it looks like it it got stuck trying to enter "FConnectionHandle.Enter"

```
procedure TIdSocketHandle.CloseSocket;
begin
  FConnectionHandle.Enter;
  try
    if HandleAllocated then
    begin
      // Bart
      syslog(LOG_NOTICE, 'IdSocketHandle.CloseSocket: HandleAllocated');
      // Must be first, closing socket will trigger some errors, and they
      // may then call (in other threads) Connected, which in turn looks at
      // FHandleAllocated.
      FHandleAllocated := False;
      syslog(LOG_NOTICE, 'IdSocketHandle.CloseSocket calls Disconnect');
      Disconnect;
      SetHandle(Id_INVALID_SOCKET);
    end else syslog(LOG_NOTICE, 'IdSocketHandle.CloseSocket: NOT HandleAllocated');
  finally
    FConnectionHandle.Leave;
  end;
end;
```

So, after a timeout (the Client is no longer answering) I call DisconnectClient:

```
function DisconnectClient(Call: string; Server: TDTBPort):boolean;
var
  Index: integer;
  List: TIdContextList;
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := false;
  
  if Server = dpOne
  then List := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList
  else List := IdTCPServer2.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    try
      Index := -1; 
      for i := 0 to List.Count-1 do
      begin
        if TDTBClient(List[i]).Callsign = Call then
        begin
          inc(TDTBClient(List[i]).TryDisconnect);
          Index := i;
          break;
        end;
      end;

      if Index >= 0 then
      begin
        result := true;
        Log('DisconnectClient: Disconnecting: Callsign='+Call+'  Port='+integer(Server).ToString+'. Index='+Index.ToString);

        // TIdContext(List[Index]).Connection.Disconnect;    
        TIdContext(List[Index]).Connection.Socket.Binding.CloseSocket;
      end else
      begin
        try
          Log('DisconnectClient: Client not found in List Port '+integer(Server).ToString+': '+Call,d_warning);
        except
          // It may now be invalid.
        end;
      end;


    except
      on E:Exception do Log('DisconnectClient: '+E.Message,d_error);
    end;
  finally
    if Server = dpOne then IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList else
    if Server = dpTwo then IdTCPServer2.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

And in the case last night, the CloseSocket Log entries where not there. This means it never got past the "FConnectionHandle.Enter".  Which is almost impossible, as this is only used *twice*: Once during Connect, and then during Disconnect. I have not been able to find any other references to this CriticalSection.
Or, the whole 'Socket' was already invalid? But then I would have expected some Exception. And the log was clean for the last 12 hours.

The Timeout system then keeps calling DisconnectClient.
Last night, after 169 times of this, the entire application died under Linux, directly after that call to CloseSocket.
No other Log entries. One moment it was there, the next moment it had disappeared.

Any advise is welcome.  I am desperate to get this fixed.

Comment: There is not enough code shown to diagnose your issue. Please provide a [mcve]. The fact that the server hangs during shutdown is usually an indication that your code is probably deadlocking itself, such as if it is trying to synchronize with the thread that is performing the shutdown. Also, `Connection.Disconnect` is known to be a little problematic on 'Nix systems across thread boundaries, but especially when SSL/TLS is used. Try using `Connection.Socket.Binding.CloseSocket` instead.

Comment: That did not work.  However, I made some changes where I unlock the list immediately after the disconnect call (because it was called from a loop of the List) and that seems to have helped.

Comment: However, I did notice another problem: When I pull the client network cable out  immediately after``` "IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1StatusInfo: SSL status: "before/accept initialization""``` then the connection hange indefinately. When I then call a Disconnect, I get shortly after a 'Segmentation fault' in unit IdSSLOpenSSL; procedure InfoCallback().  Is there a way to set a timeout in the SSL negotiation so it drops the connection when the link dies in the middle (or directly after the "before/accept initialization"?

Comment: The segfault is probably related to https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/218. As for the timeout, you can try setting the connection/IOHandler's `ReadTimeout`, though you might need to resort to setting the `SO_RCVTIMEO`/`SO_SENDTIMEO` options directly on the underlying socket instead.

Comment: In function GetProxyTargetHost I added: `{$ifdef POSIX}
  Binding.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_RCVTIMEO, 10000);
  Binding.SetSockOpt(Id_SOL_SOCKET, Id_SO_SNDTIMEO, 10000);
  {$ENDIF}`  But it did not work.

Comment: `GetProxyTargetHost()` isn't a good place for that. I would have put it higher in `OpenEncodedConnection()` where the timeouts are being set on Windows Vista+. Or even in the server's `OnConnect` eventas a test before modifying Indy's code..

Comment: Update: I have been stress testing the 'Disconnect' issue now for several days. 99 times out of 100 it works okay. Then the disconnect fails; and I get a Segmentation Fault in `function TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Readable()` in the call to `ssl_pending(fSSLSocket.fSSL)`.  I have also switched to use `Connection.Socket.Binding.CloseSocket` as per your recommendation, but I don't think this made any difference. I also implemented your Fix in 'issues/218' in the code (why has this never been implemented?). Is there anything I can change in the Indy code to solve this problem at the source?

Comment: "*why has [your Fix in 'issues/218'] never been implemented?*" - because I never had a chance to verify it for myself yet. "*Is there anything I can change in the Indy code to solve this problem at the source?*" - everything I have suggested so far would be exactly that.

Comment: You actually did verify it for yourself... Have another look at it. Which is why I changed it here as per your idea. I have implemented the two ideas you posted here, but unfortunately the problem of the Disconnect causing intermittant serious problems persists. Not only I get critical exceptions, but also when I catch these, I end up with a permanent, not-clearing, entry in the Context list, which cannot be removed. While at the same time this entry is *not* called anymore in the OnExecute. But my server cannot accept a new connection from the same source while one still exists in the list.

Comment: "*You actually did verify it for yourself*" - no, I have not compiled and run the code to see if the new behavior works, hence why the ticket is still open. I don't have a working compiler installed, and have not for awhile now. And even if I did, I'm not a Linux user. I have never run code on Linux. So I couldnt verify this fixes your issue even if I wanted to. So you are going to have to debug it for yourself, and submit a patch if you find a fix.

Comment: Ah, okay. I am happy to give it a try, but there is much in the Indy source which I don't understand. Is there still any work done on Indy, and who is doing it? Also, based on my description, any ideas or hints you can give me where the problem could be? Especially because this has worked perfectly for many years in production running under Windows. And if I cannot find a solution for this in Linux, I have to abandon this entire project, with major repercussions to the VPS I have already ordered from the New Zealand goverment for Search and Rescue :(

Comment: "*Is there still any work done on Indy*" - yes, it is still actively developed. It is [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy). "*who is doing it?*" - I am the primary (but not the original) developer of Indy. "*any ideas or hints you can give me where the problem could be?*" - I honestly couldn't say, with the limited information provided so far.

Comment: Okay thanks Remy. I am going to dig deeper. And thanks for all your help over the years!